# UPDATE table using CONCAT_WS error

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, concat-ws

I have 2 tables named vhistory and week2.  vhistory includes two columns voternum and voterhistory.  week2 contains columns age, address, voternum, voterhistory, status, gender, precinct, county, and zip5.  I need to update week2 voterhistory using table vhistory where week2 voternum = vhistory voternum.

For example:
Within week2 there is a person with voternum = 1234.
Within vhistory there are 3 records where voternum = 1234.
One has a voterhistory = 2011, one has a voterhistory = 2012, and one has a voterhistory = 2013.
This means when updating week2 the 3 records of vhistory should import into the voterhistory column of the week2 table like so:  2011, 2012, 2013.

This is what I have so far.

```
UPDATE week2 SET voterhistory=SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',SELECT voterhistory FROM vhistory
WHERE week2.voternum = vhistory.voternum );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an update-join statement is what you're looking for:

```
UPDATE week2 
JOIN   (SELECT   voternum, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(voterhistory ORDER BY voterhistory SEPARATOR ',') 
                   AS history
        FROM     vhistory
        GROUP BY voternum) h ON week2.voternum = h.voternum
SET    voterhistory = history
```

Comment: what is "h" and I am receiving an error "near 'ORDER BY voterhistory SEPARATOR ',') 
                   AS history
        FR' at line 3 "

Comment: I had an extra whitespace after `group_concat` - fixed. To your question - `h` is the alias I gave the aggregate query in order to perform the `join`.

Comment: Alright. The query seems to be working, but is taking a while to complete. Is that expected? There are over 400k rows in the week2 and vhistory tables.

Comment: Anything you do on a table with 400K is bound to take some time - especially as you're updating all the rows here... are the `voternum` columns in both tables indexed?

Comment: The query completed eventually.  Thanks a lot!!